# Easy OCR not installing

Tags: easyocr

When I tried to download easy ocr in my python project, but I am receiving this error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
  ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2, 1.22.3, 1.22.4, 1.23.0rc1, 1.23.0rc2, 1.23.0rc3, 1.23.0, 1.23.1, 1.23.2, 1.23.3, 1.23.4, 1.23.5, 1.24.0rc1, 1.24.0rc2, 1.24.0, 1.24.1, 1.24.2)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.21.2
```

Comment: You almost certainly need to upgrade your version of Python. Please edit your Python version into your question so we can know for sure.

Comment: Packages can choose which Python version they want to distribute to. OP, if your Python is too old, it is probably the cause.

Comment: I am on the latest version of python. Python 11

Comment: Likewise on Python 11 and latest numpy is 1.24.2 but easyocr insists 1.21.2 which pip complains does not even exist.

Comment: Here's what pip says:  `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.21.2 (from versions: ..., 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.22.0, ...)` (compress the huge list of versions to fit as a comment here).